# FluentValidation range throws InvalidOperationException in Razor view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel, fluentvalidation

i'm working with ASP MVC 5, and i'm pretty new using FluentValidation.

I'm trying to validate a simple range.

I have a class like this

```
public int Property { get; set; }
```

And this is my validation

```
RuleFor(x => x.Property).NotEmpty()
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(1)
                .LessThanOrEqualTo(20);
```

When i want to use it in razor view using `EditorFor`

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FactorK)
```

It throws a `InvalidOperationException`

> System.InvalidOperationException: The names of the validation types in
>   discrete client validation rules must be unique. The following type of
>   validation has been observed more than once: range

The strange thing is that when trying to use only one method (`GreaterThanOrEqual` or `LessThanOrEqual`) it works ok.

For Example,

```
RuleFor(x => x.Property).NotEmpty()
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(1);
```

This works.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message explain the reason of error, both GreaterThanOrEqualTo and LessThanOrEqualTo are of "range" validation type.
Try to use InclusiveBetween instead.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation, i found the [`InclusiveBetween` validator](https://fluentvalidation.net/built-in-validators#inclusivebetween-validator).

That was the solution for me.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Property).NotEmpty()
    .InclusiveBetween(1, 20);
```